# Почему json_decode работает со строкой из массивов?

Tags: php, json

Сегодня стало открытием для меня, что даже строка вида:

```
$json = '[["test2", "test2"], "yo1", ["message1", "msg2", ["bing1", "bang", "oops"], "msg3"]]';
```

спокойно при помощи

```
json_decode($json);
```

конвертируется в обычный массив:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => test2
            [1] => test2
        )

    [1] => yo1
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => message1
            [1] =>; msg2
            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => bing1
                    [1] => bang
                    [2] => oops
                )

            [3] => msg3
        )   
)
```

Как такое может быть? За счет чего?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строка, приведенная вами в примере вполне удовлетворяет спецификации.

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> - A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
>     realized as an *object*, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>     list, or associative array.
> - An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an
>     *array*, vector, list, or sequence.
>
> ... An *array* is an ordered collection of values. An array begins with
>   [ (left bracket) and ends with ] (right bracket). Values are separated
>   by , (comma).
>
> A *value* can be a *string* in double quotes, or a *number*, or true or
>   false or null, or an *object* or an *array*. These structures can be
>   nested.

[Оригинал статьи](http://www.json.org/)

**Перевод:**

> JSON строится на двух структурах
>
> - Коллекция пар ключ/значение. В разных языках, эта концепция реализована как *объект*, запись, структура, словарь, хэш, именованный
>     список или ассоциативный массив.
> - Упорядоченный список значений. В большинстве языков это реализовано как *массив*, вектор, список или последовательность.
>
> ... *Массив* - упорядоченная коллекция значений. Массив начинается с [
>   (открывающей квадратной скобки) и заканчивается ] (закрывающей
>   квадратной скобкой). Значения разделены , (запятой).
>
> *Значение* может быть *строкой* в двойных кавычках, *числом*, true, false, null, *объектом* или *массивом*. Эти структуры могут быть
>   вложенными.

[Оригинал статьи](http://www.json.org/json-ru.html)

Таким образом, в строке у нас содержится массив, первым элементом которого является другой массив, обоими элементами которого являются строки "test2" и "test2", следующий элемент -- строка "yo1", и так далее.

Comment: т.к. это [ru.so], то перевод не помешает.

Comment: http://www.json.org/json-ru.html =)

Comment: а вот ссылки не приветствуются

Comment: Сейчас поправлю ответ, не подумал.

Comment: спасибо, уже добавили. рекомендуется добавлять перевод, т.к. все таки это раздел so на русском, а ссылки на источники со временем могут быть битыми.

Comment: Спасибо за форматирование, и правки. Учту.

Comment: кек. интересно. век живи - век учись